# How to link against x86 .lib on x64 machine with rustc (64 bit) on Windows?

Tags: c++, rust, x86, static-libraries

I am building a rust application that links against a C++ library that has a C interface exposed.  I am running on an x64 windows machine and rust was installed with rustup-init.exe (64-bit). I installed  When I run `cargo build` I get the following error.

```
= note: sanitized_auth_test_1.qvct9jv5vjn41op.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol encryptLogonAuth referenced in function _ZN21sanitized_auth_test_14main17hf80bd6c03de31c54E
          sanitized_auth_test_1.qvct9jv5vjn41op.rcgu.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol initEncryption referenced in function _ZN21sanitized_auth_test_14main17hf80bd6c03de31c54E
          lib\\ClientAuth.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x86' conflicts with target machine type 'x64'
          C:\Users\XXX\development\sanitized_auth_test_1\target\debug\deps\sanitized_auth_test_1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I have tried running the above command in x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for Vs 2022, x86_64 Cross Tools Command Prompt for Vs 2022, and x86 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022.  The error is the same in all of them.
Below is the verbose output of my cargo and rust versions

```
 rustc --version --verbose
rustc 1.70.0-nightly (700938c07 2023-04-04)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 700938c0781c9f135244bb1ec846fe1a5e03ae7d
commit-date: 2023-04-04
host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
release: 1.70.0-nightly
LLVM version: 16.0.0
PS C:\Users\xxx\development\sanitized_auth_test_1> cargo --version --verbose
cargo 1.70.0-nightly (0e474cfd7 2023-03-31)
release: 1.70.0-nightly
commit-hash: 0e474cfd7b16b018cf46e95da3f6a5b2f1f6a9e7
commit-date: 2023-03-31
host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
libgit2: 1.5.0 (sys:0.16.0 vendored)
libcurl: 8.0.1-DEV (sys:0.4.61+curl-8.0.1 vendored ssl:Schannel)
os: Windows 10.0.22000 (Windows 10 Pro) [64-bit]
```

Here is the directory structure

```
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----          4/6/2023   8:00 AM                include
d-----          4/6/2023   8:00 AM                lib
d-----          4/6/2023   7:56 AM                src
d-----          4/6/2023   8:01 AM                target
-a----          4/5/2023  12:09 PM              9 .gitignore
-a----          4/6/2023   7:58 AM            228 build.rs
-a----          4/6/2023   7:58 AM            165 Cargo.lock
-a----          4/6/2023   7:58 AM            178 Cargo.toml
```

The contents of .\include\ClientAuth.h (the header file for the lib)

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif          /* __cplusplus */
        void initEncryption(void);
        int encryptLogonAuth(   unsigned int sessionID,
                                                        unsigned int vendorID,
                                                        unsigned int productID,
                                                        unsigned int bigEndian,
                                                        char* outBuff);
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif          /* __cplusplus */
```

The x86 ClientAuth.lib is under .\lib.

.\src\main.rs

```
use std::os::raw::c_char;
#[link(name = "ClientAuth", kind = "static")]
extern "C" {
    fn initEncryption();
    fn encryptLogonAuth(
        session_id: u32,
        vendor_id: u32,
        product_id: u32,
        big_endian: u32,
        out_buff: *mut c_char,
    ) -> i32;
}

fn main() {
    let session_id: u32 = 0;
    let vendor_id: u32 = 0;
    let big_endian: u32 = 0;
    let product_id: u32 = 0;
    let mut out_buff: [c_char; 16] = Default::default();

    unsafe {
        let _ = encryptLogonAuth(
            session_id,
            vendor_id,
            product_id,
            big_endian,
            out_buff.as_mut_ptr(),
        );
        initEncryption();
    }
}
```

build.rs

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=lib/");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=ClientAuth");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/main.rs");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/ClientAuth.h");
}
```

and finally Cargo.toml

```
[package]
name = "sanitized_auth_test_1"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
```

Is there a way to link the x86 ClientAuth.lib on an x64 machine with the x64 version cargo/rustc?  I cannot rebuild the library as I am not provided the source for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: f you only have a 32bit lib, you need to build a 32bit binary. I dunno how rust does this, but I guess you should be able to find pointers e.g. here: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-build-both-32-and-64-bit-app-on-windows/26365

Comment: Yeah, you'll need to use the `x86-pc-windows-msvc` target instead.

Comment: when I run ```rustup target list```I don't see x86-pc-windows-msvc?  The x86 target seems to be i686-pc-windows-msvc. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The fix was to run

```
rustup target add i686-pc-windows-msvc
```

and then run

```
cargo b --target=i686-pc-windows-msvc
```

I also needed to modify build.rs

```
fn main() {
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=lib/");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib=ClientAuth");

    println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=/SAFESEH:NO");
    println!("cargo:rustc-link-arg=/NODEFAULTLIB:libc.lib");

    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=src/main.rs");
    println!("cargo:rerun-if-changed=include/ClientAuth.h");
}
```

so that when I run

```
cargo r --target=i686-pc-windows-msvc
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.14s
     Running `target\i686-pc-windows-msvc\debug\sanitized_auth_test_1.exe`
```